# Homebrew brew exports

Tags: sync, export, homebrew, import

Looking for a way to export my Homebrew and Homebrew Cask installations (everything from `brew list` and `brew cask list`)

I'd like to be able to export them to a file that I can then put on any new machine, and run some sort of install that will install them automatically.

Basically using something like a `package.json` for package management.

Answer (score 0):

[Brew-file](https://github.com/rcmdnk/homebrew-file) is providing a full support for syncing brew install across machines.